# Modbus ascii Timeout implementation

Tags: ascii, modbus

Quoting from the [MODBUS over Serial Line
Specification and Implementation Guide
V1.02](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf):

> Intervals of up to one second may elapse between characters within the
>   message. Unless the user has configured a longer timeout, an interval
>   greater than 1 second means an error has occurred. Some
>   Wide-Area-Network application may require a timeout in the 4 to 5
>   second range

I would like to know how to set a longer time out and how this timer configuration is handled in modbus ASCII. Please share me any links available for more information.

Comment: How you configure the modbus timeouts will depend on what tools you are using. Please provide additional details (e.g. programming language & Modbus library or info on the device you are trying to configure).

Comment: HI, currently i am using Mdbus tool and STM32 controller. MDbus tool configured as "Master" and STM32F4 controller configured as "Slave device".(programming language: 'C')

Comment: Here i am getting response from the slave, but how to configure intervals of up to one second may elapse between characters within the message (i am using docklight tool to create delay between the characters, even if delay is more than one second also getting response from the slave)

Comment: Please provide some more info re the STM32 - i.e. What modbus library are you using? I gather that you want to know why the STM32 is not rejecting a modbus request when there are intercharacter delays over 1s; this timeout will be implemented within whichever modbus library you are using.

Comment: yes correct .  Here i was created some functions to handle TX and RX with help of STM hal libraries(No modbus library API used), I want to know how to handle or configure these time out, Please let me know if any example libraries available to understand timeout implementation.

Comment: OK - A quick google reveals [this](https://github.com/MahdiKarimian/STM32-Modbus-SerialDMA/blob/master/modbus/ascii/mbascii.c#L240) (timeout set [here](https://github.com/MahdiKarimian/STM32-Modbus-SerialDMA/blob/master/modbus/ascii/mbascii.c#L120) and implementation [here](https://github.com/MahdiKarimian/STM32-Modbus-SerialDMA/blob/master/modbus/port/porttimer.c#L32) but I'd be very suprised if you have not already found that? Perhaps post the code you have (however I think you would need a good reason to reimplement modbus when there are a range of existing libraries).

Comment: Thank you .. I will try to implement timeout logic and update the same.